# TinyMce - How to fix this dropdown menu

Tags: html, tinymce-4

I created a CodePen to help illustrate the issue:  [TinyMCE Menu Issue](http://codepen.io/bdogi/pen/VmxWYR)

```
tinymce.init({
          selector: 'textarea',
          menu: {
              file: { title: 'File', items: 'newdocument' },
              edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
              insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr' },
              view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid' },
              format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat' },
              table: { title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column' },
              tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' },
              myapp: { title: 'My Application', items: 'myapp' }
          },
          plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
          ],
          toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
          toolbar2: 'forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
          image_advtab: true,
          content_css: [
            '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
            '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
          ],
          setup: function (editor) {
              editor.addMenuItem('myapp', {
                  text: 'My Application',
                  context: 'myapp',
                  menu: [{
                      text: 'Data Loop',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Data}');
                      }
                  }, {
                      text: 'Collection Loop',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Collection}');
                      }

                  }, {
                      text: 'Process Loop',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Process}');
                      }

                  }, {
                      text: 'Server Name',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{ServerName}');
                      }

                  }, {
                      text: 'Email Group Name',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{EmailGroupName}');
                      }

                  }, {
                      text: 'Alert Group Name',
                      onclick: function () {
                          editor.insertContent('{AlertGroupName}');
                      }

                  }]
              });
          }

      });
```

If you look at that codepen, you will see that the 'My Application' menu actually drops down twice, which I don't really want.  I want a simple one-level dropdown.  Not sure why I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create each button separately and add them to the toolbar.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  menu: {
    file: { title: 'File', items: 'newdocument' },
    edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
    insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr' },
    view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid' },
    format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat' },
    table: { title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column' },
    tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' },
    myapp: { title: 'My Application', items: 'myapp1 myapp2 myapp3 myapp4  myapp5 myapp6 myapp7' }
  },
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
  image_advtab: true,
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ],
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp1', {
      text: 'Data Loop',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Data}');
      }
    });
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp2', {
      text: 'Collection Loop',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Collection}');
      }
    });
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp4', {
      text: 'Process Loop',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{LOOP:Process}');
      }
    });
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp5', {
      text: 'Server Name',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{ServerName}');
      }

    });
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp6', {
      text: 'Email Group Name',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{EmailGroupName}');
      }

    });
    editor.addMenuItem('myapp7', {
      text: 'Alert Group Name',
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('{AlertGroupName}');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This is the update to your codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zojzoL

Comment: Ah!!!  Thank you.  I had a button previously, but didn't think I could add it to the menu.  I changed it to MenuItem before I pushed it to the top menu.  Argh!  Much appreciated @Dekel!